# С клавиатуры ввести массив целых чисел

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 25

int main()
{
system("chcp 1251");
int arr[N];
int* p1,
* p2,
* pel;

p1 = &arr[0],
p2 = p1 + N - 1;
int k = 0;

int arr2[N],
    * parr2,
    * parr3;

printf("\nВведіть елементи (не більше %d), кінець введення – "
    "довільний символ \n", N);
while (k < N) {
    if (scanf("%d", arr + k) == 0)
        break;
    k++;
}


parr2 = &arr2[0];
parr3 = parr2 + N - 1;

    for (pel = arr+1; pel < p2; pel++) 

        pel % p1 == 0;
        parr2 = pel;
    
for (; parr2 < parr3; parr2++)
    printf("%4d", *parr2);
return 0;
```

}

> С клавиатуры ввести массив целых чисел . Сформировать новый массив из тех элементов введенного массива, которые целочисленных делятся на его первый элемент. напечатать созданный массив или вывести сообщение об отсутствии таких элементов.
>
> Не очень понимаю как делать но что-то попытался сделать

Answer (score 1):

1. Если у вас цикл идет строго до `p2`, то должно быть так `p2 = p1 + N` без добавления единицы.
2. Вот пример кода, после введения чисел, с комментариями:

   ```
   //Указатель на начало массива arr2
   parr2 = &arr2[0];
   //Указатель на k элемент, т.к. k - кол-во введенных чисел (< N)
   parr3 = parr2 + k;
   //указатель на начало массива arr
   p1 = &arr[0];
   //Указатель на k элемент
   p2 = p1 + k;
   //Кол-во элементов целочисленно делящихся на первый элемент
   int count = 0;

   //Проходим по всем введенным элементам
   for (pel = p1; pel < p2; pel++) {
       if (*pel % arr[0] == 0) {
           //Если делится, то вносим элемент в массив arr2
           *parr2 = *pel;
           ++parr2;
           ++count;
       }
   }

   //И выводим элементы массива arr2
   parr2 = &arr2[0];
   parr3 = parr2 + count;

   for (; parr2 < parr3; parr2++)
       printf("%4d", *parr2);
   ```